# How to get data from regular expression from a string in key value pair

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

There's a following string:

```
pTzNmfaQdxVSvoDJPVtSh-idt(null).jpeg
```

and a matcher:

```
def matcher = imageName =~ (?<imageKey>\w+)(\-(?<state>.+))?\.(?<ext>\w+)
```

`imageNAme` is equal to `pTzNmfaQdxVSvoDJPVtSh-idt(null).jpeg`

How to construct the following hierarchy?

`[matcher.group("imageKey"), matcher.group("state"), matcher.group("ext")]`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below regex to grab `pTzNmfaQdxVSvoDJPVtSh`, `-idt(null)`, `jpeg` into separate groups.

```
^([^\-]*)(-[^\.]*)\.(.*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eU3rG4/4)

Comment: def matcher = imageName =~ (?<imageKey>\w+)(\-(?<encodedTransformState>.+))?\.(?<ext>\w+)

Comment: does it helps? If no, i will delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if your question is how to deal with the matcher, or how to put the results in a List.

This may help:

```
def src = 'pTzNmfaQdxVSvoDJPVtSh-idt(null).jpeg'
def matcher = src =~ /^([^\-]*)(-[^\.]*)\.(.*)$/
def match = matcher[0]

def result = [match[1], match[2], match[3]]

assert result[0] == 'pTzNmfaQdxVSvoDJPVtSh'
assert result[1] == '-idt(null)'
assert result[2] == 'jpeg'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the machanism how you solve it as I have no knowledge how to deal with regex.Thanks